# sending email by jsp

Tags: java, jsp, email

I am trying to design a jsp page where I can send an e-mail but the code which is properly running in core java is giving me exception when used in jsp code. I believe I have properly placed my mail.jar in lib.

The current jsp code is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>

                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

                <html>
                <body>

                <%@ page import="java.util.Properties" %>               
                <%@ page import="javax.mail.Message" %>
                <%@ page import="javax.mail.MessagingException" %>
                <%@ page import="javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication" %>
                <%@ page import="javax.mail.Session" %>
                <%@ page import="javax.mail.Transport" %>
                <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress" %>
                <%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage" %>


                <%
                Properties props = new Properties();
                        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                 Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                    return new PasswordAuthentication("prakash.d2222","**************");
                                }
                            });

                        try {

                            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
                            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                    InternetAddress.parse("prakash_d22@rediffmail.com"));
                            message.setSubject("hi");
                            message.setText("12345" +
                                    "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

                            Transport.send(message);

                            System.out.println("Done");

                        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                %>
                </body>
                </html>
```

and the error that I'm seeing is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 37 in the jsp file: /pizza/page/ssl.jsp
The constructor MimeMessage(HttpSession) is undefined
```

Comment: -1 for the rude and disrespectful "gimme the codez" behaviour in comments. On an unrelated note, please learn to separate the concerns. This specific problem has actually nothing to do with JSP. You should first have created a standalone class which does all the JavaMail job and have used a plain Java application with `main()` method to test it. Once you get it to work, all you need to do is to call that newly created class/method in JSP (or, better, [Servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)).

Comment: i did it man and it ran properly in core java but giving problem in jsp only

Comment: thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session ); // error
```

In JSP page session is a implicit object which is actually javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.

I think you are confused with HttpSession and mail javax.mail.Session.Session. Change you 
code like -
...

```
 Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                    protected PasswordAuthentication 
                                          getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                        return new PasswordAuthentication
                                          ("prakash.d2222","**************");
                                    }
                                });
```

...

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession );
```

...

Comment: now session is showing an exception .used try and catch but e mail not sent.but the previous error was solved thnks .

Comment: Can you please provide the stack-trace

Comment: thanks  below code worked      try {  
   Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     return new PasswordAuthentication("prakash.d2222","**********");
    }
   });
     
      
     
       Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

Comment: @prakash_d22 - please try with full email id here - 'new PasswordAuthentication("me@domain.com", "secrect");'

Comment: no probs with above code also both are working fine thanks again will ask for help again if needed further in my jsp website

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15465/discussion-between-quoi-and-prakash-d22)

Answer (score 7):

Exactly as the error message tells you, [there is no `MimeMessage` constructor that takes an `HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html). There *is* a constructor which takes a [`javax.mail.Session`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Session.html), which appears to be the one you're trying to use, but an [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is not a `javax.mail.Session`.

Pass the value returned by `Session.getDefaultInstance()`, which you're currently discarding.

```
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("prakash.d2222","**************");
        }
});

// ...

Message message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
```

Comment: Pass a `javax.mail.Session` and not an `HttpSession`.

Comment: @prakash_d22, please, show some effort solving your own problem. SO is not a *gimme the codez* kinda website. please have a go reading [the FAQ entry on this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: @MattBall, +1 for the tolerance :)

Comment: @MattBall it worked once but its showing error on Session declaration line

Comment: @prakash_d22 and the error is...? Come on, dude. Have you put in _any_ effort to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: Have you tried actually reading the compiler error messages? You could at least give us the full information - again: **what is the error you're seeing?**

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /pizza/page/ssl.jsp at line 28

25:   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
26:   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
27: 
28:   Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
29:                                 new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
30:                                     protected PasswordAuthentication 
31:                                           getPasswordAuthentication() {

Comment: That's not enough information. Put a proper stack trace in your question.